# How to read spreadsheet formula value in ruby

Tags: ruby, encoding, spreadsheet

I am using spreadsheet gem to read the values from excel file in ruby.

Example:-

```
key value

test 1
```

While reading value of test(value=1) and comparing value with 1. Am getting the following error

```
<"#<Spreadsheet::Formula:0x000000043aa990>">("ASCII-8BIT") expected but was
  <"1">("US-ASCII").

Expected: From spreadsheet value
Result: static value
```

How do i resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the encoding, something like this:

```
Spreadsheet.client_encoding = 'UTF-8'
```

Comment: have u added magic comment line in the beginning # encoding: utf-8